# How to insert text into mysql having quotes using perl

Tags: mysql, perl

How to insert text into mysql having quotes using perl ?
It seems difficult to insert text containing ' & ".
I'm using Perl DBI module & DB is mysql.

UPDATE:

here is my query

```
my $s = "INSERT INTO comment(guid,review_id) VALUES ('$guid','$review_id')";
```

Comment: you escape the text before entering in in your db, show your current code

Comment: my $s = "insert into comment(guid,review_id,) values ('$guid','$review_id')";

Comment: Ignore @mandy's advice. It is both dangerous and incorrect. The correct way to do it is using placeholders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your old query would have been something like this:

```
my $s = "insert into comment(guid,review_id) values ('$guid','$review_id')";
$dbh->do($s);
```

The better way, using placeholders and bind values as per @AlexD's answer, would look like this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into comment(guid,review_id) values (?, ?)";);
$sth->execute($guid, $review_id);
```

To learn about the security risks of your first approach, have a look at [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, using `prepare` and `execute` would be more effective if `execute` is called multiple times inside loop.

Answer (score 13):

You should read section '[Placeholders and Bind Values](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values)' in `man DBI`

EDIT: added example

```
my $s = "insert into comment(guid,review_id) values (?, ?)";
$dbh->do( $s, undef, $guid, $review_id) or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Comment: Absolutely. It's not only easier to code; it's also faster and more secure.

Comment: Can you please show the small example ! Please or how would change my code here.